# How to extend the background in a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Here is a small (silly) code of a shiny dashboard application:

```
    library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("choices")),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$choices <- renderUI(radioButtons("blabla", NULL, 1:100))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When you run this code, you see that if you scroll down, the nice background on the right hand side suddenly switches to black. How do I make sure that the background stays nice and uniform throughout the entire page, even if a scroll down and use ui-elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overwrite fixed height to your **.content-wrapper** class.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 3000px !important;}'))),
        uiOutput("choices")),
    dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input,output) {
    output$choices <- renderUI(radioButtons("blabla", NULL, 1:100))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but I'm adding here for posterity. I did not find a fixed height to be satisfactory as it adds a permanent scrollbar.

Using `.content-wrapper { overflow: auto; }` seems to work as I expect. I.e.:

```
dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        # ...
    ),
    dashboardBody(

        # ...

        tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper { overflow: auto; }')))
    )
)
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver!